# Date Picker Validations

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I have the following [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oHAgu/2)

What I would like to achieve here is when the Edit button is clicked

1) Date picker should have dates which are greater than End Date if Proj End Date is is empty

2) Date picker should have dates which are greater than Proj End Date if Proj End Date is is not empty

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/olUMU)

**Update 1:-**

I have implemented below function in above code:

1. If `projEndDate` field have no value then its minimum value should be greater (or equal to) 'EndDate' field.
2. If `projEndDate` field have value then its minimum value should greater (or equal to) `projEndDate` field.

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: This works fine when Proj. End Date exist in grid, but for rows which do not have Proj. End Date, validation doesn't work. e.g. first, third and so forth. See [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/iVElA)

Comment: I have added my understanding in my above post. Let me know if I am incorrect. in-addition I have also verified it and its working fine for me.

Comment: I have updated my above code accordingly.  Could you please copy-paste above code in kendo dojo and check it again.

Comment: Still are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103283/discussion-between-jayesh-goyani-and-user75ponic).